# WriteFile then immediately ReadFile WINAPI

Tags: c++, readfile, createprocess

In the code below, I'm trying to write the output of a process to a file, then read the information that was just put in there.  I can do it properly if I write to the file, close the file, wait a few seconds for the file to close properly, then open the file again and read from it.  The problem is that I really don't want to have to close a file just to reopen it, and if I do close it, I have to put a delay in there since I can't close it and then immediately reopen the same file or I get a blank result.  My guess is that because the file didn't close, the handle is starting to read from the point that the writing left off at.

```
HANDLE hLog = CreateFile("test.log",
                          GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                          NULL,
                          CREATE_ALWAYS,
                          FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                          NULL);

if (hLog == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    return FALSE;
}

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));

HANDLE hCurOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hLog);

BOOL bResult = CreateProcess(NULL,
                           "Test.exe",
                           NULL,
                           NULL,
                           FALSE,
                           0,
                           NULL,
                           NULL,
                           &si,
                           &pi);

SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hCurOutput);

if (bResult == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}

TCHAR data[1024] = {0};
DWORD dwBytesRead;

bResult = ReadFile(hLog, data, sizeof(data), &dwBytesRead, NULL);

std::cout << data << "\n";

CloseHandle(hLog);

return bResult;
```

I'm sticking with only WinAPI's for this as well.  But everytime I ReadFile, it's blank and dwBytesRead is 0.  Is there a way to reset my current position in the file so I can read from the beginning?

Comment: You should be checking the return value of `SetStdHandle` to make sure there is no error.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @AndyG You're right, I should, but that's not giving me my error in the scenario.  I'll add that in too.

Comment: @dutt I mentioned what I'm trying to do. I want to run a program (ie: test.exe) and have it output the information it would normally output in the console to a text file.  It does that properly (I can open the text file in notepad and see the contents).  Then I'm trying to read that content back in so I can parse it.

Comment: There are other ways which probably are easier for that, call your writer from the reader and read process stdout, or use an IPC framework. IPC is sometimes called shared memory and other things too.

Comment: @dutt Are you talking about this example [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx) I tried that but kept getting access denied errors in my ReadFile.

Comment: Kind of a strange thing to want to do.  Using CREATE_ALWAYS is certainly a mistake, that destroys the file.

Comment: @HansPassant Definitely not a mistake, I want to recreate the file everytime

Comment: While not the original answer I was looking for, I ended up solving my overall issue by creating a pipe to a handle and piping the output of my CreateProcess through the pipe and using that to read the data.